# How to simplify those tow macro when runtime type depend?

Tags: macros, clojure, case

guys,
look at the code first:

```
(defmacro map-remove- [v w]
  `(dosync
     (ref-set ~v (dissoc @~v (keyword ~w)))))
(defmacro set-remove- [v w]
  `(dosync
     (ref-set ~v (disj @~v ~w))))
(defmacro clean- [v] 
  `(dosync
    (ref-set ~v (empty @~v))))
```

They work fine now , but I want write a more general macro to combine "map-remove-" and "set-remove-" in one. according my C/Java experience I chose "case" but obviously the case can't use in macro defination cause "The test-constants are not evaluated. They must be compile-time literals", the following code won't work:

```
(defmacro [x]
  (case (type x) ;;;;;;;;;;; This will never work!directly reach to default clause 
    ....))
```

anybody has any suggestion? very appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the functions `map?` and `set?` to test whether a value is a map or a set respectively.

I'm not sure I have enough perspective on what you're trying to do here though - I've substituted a macro instead of a function, because I can't see the necessity for a macro in the sample you've given.

```
;; Create a function to remove in a different way when given a map/set and a string
(defn remove- [v w]
  (dosync
     (cond 
        (map? @v)
        (ref-set v (dissoc @v (keyword w)))

        (set? @v)
        (ref-set v (disj @v w)))))

 ;; Set up some mutable refs
 (def m (ref {:a 1 :b 2}))
 (def s (ref #{"a" "b" "c"}))

 ;; Remove from the refs
 (remove- m "b") => {:a 1}
 (remove- s "b") => #{"a" "c"}
```

On a side note - are you *sure* you need to use refs? I know that coming from a C/Java background, mutability is the default, but I've never actually had to use it in Clojure so far. Clojure places a lot of emphasis on immutability, and most things can be done (often very elegantly) just by using functions on immutable values.

Comment: Thank u,Daniel. your code works. thank u very much. Yes I should use 'refs' cause I use :
`(def dict (ref {})) ; glob
(def stranger (ref #{}))`

Comment: Thank u,Daniel. your code works. thank u very much. Yes I should use 'refs' cause I use :
`(def dict (ref {})) `
`(def stranger (ref #{}))`
at the begining of my code, as the 'variables' are not VARIABLE.... though I think I konw c/Java well, clojure always make me a fool